# Is there a better version of vim which is not implemented in vimL?

Tags: vimscript

I'm wondering why vim is implemented using vimL? Is there other version of vim which is implemented with other modern language like python, javascript?

I know javascript and python, I just don't want to learn vimL, it looks too complex to me... sometimes I want to write a plugin for myself only find I need to learn vimL first.

I know vim somehow support writing plugins using python or other. But I just want to know if there's already a "clean" version that completely implemented using modern programming language?

Comment: You can try [snake](https://github.com/amoffat/snake) as an "alternative" to VimL. I haven't used it though so I cannot say much about it. All the VimL required is to setup your vimrc file to load the plugin. The rest is python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim is *not* implemented in VimL. Vim is implemented in C. As is NeoVim, a fork. Vim's *runtime* features are written in VimL, but the core is C. There's no Vim implementation I know of that's in JavaScript.

To write plugins in Vim, you have a few choices aside from VimL:

- [Lua](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_lua.txt.html#if_lua.txt)
- [TCL](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_tcl.txt.html#if_tcl.txt)
- [Perl](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_perl.txt.html#if_perl.txt)
- [Python](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_pyth.txt.html#if_pyth.txt)
- [Ruby](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_ruby.txt.html#if_ruby.txt)
- [Racket](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_mzsch.txt.html#if_mzsch.txt)

You can get away with minimal knowledge of VimL, if you know one of these languages.

If you don't like it, try another editor with Vim keybindings, like [Atom](https://github.com/atom/vim-mode) (which is written in JavaScript),  or maybe Sublime Text. But plugins written for Vim won't work there, so good luck!

Comment: Your answer if perfectly right, I just want to mention that someone did release a [clone of Vim](https://github.com/coolwanglu/vim.js) written in Javascript that you can [try online](https://coolwanglu.github.io/vim.js/emterpreter/vim.html) it is far from being as complete and functional as the original vim but that exists :-)

Comment: Beside, I'd add that VimL is extremely close to what vim offers through its command line. All vim variables, functions that can be used with `:substitute`, etc. are in VimL.